# Adding Decimal(x) to an array

Tags: python, arrays, decimal

When I append a `Decimal(x)` value to an array I would like to just get the number but it also includes the `Decimal()` function call at the start of the element.

Code:

```
array = []
a = Decimal(0.000005342)
array.append(a)
print(array)
```

Output:

```
[Decimal('0.0000053419999999999998450852904674501786530527169816195964813232421875')]
```

Comment: That *is* the number. Also note you shouldn't create `Decimal`s from floats - as you can see, you lose precision over `Decimal('0.000005342')`.

Comment: The reason to use a string is because floating point on computers is approximate. See question [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) Also note that your variable named `array` is a Python **`list`**, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing printed out is the `repr()` of the list. This is a `repr`esentation that when printed out and executed should result in an equal object. To view the `str` of the object, you have to manually call `str` on the `Decimal` instances:

```
print(", ".join(str(d) for d in array))
```

Comment: It should be noted that your solution is still going to print `0.0000053419999999999998450852904674501786530527169816195964813232421875` because of the way the `Decimal` instance is being created.